# What AWS Code Pipeline Stage best to put ECR Docker image updates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

We plan to use ECR to host our application docker images. To do this, we intend to push the latest version of the of our application docker image to ECR every build prior to deploy.

Currently we use Code Build to build out application artifact. Do we put in the ECR image push in the Code Build Step as well? Or is there a better aws service for that?

Here our current pipeline setup:

Source(Pull from Github) -> CodeBuild(Build jar, build docker with jar, push to ECR) -> Deploy(deploy application using the latest ECR image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Build and Push of Docker image should be in the build step and this is the AWS recommended approach as discussed in this blog article:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cd-pipeline.html